# Specify the number of characters that should match a LIKE REGEX in T-SQL

Tags: regex, t-sql, teradata, regexp-substr

I've done a ton of Googling on this and can't find the answer. Or, at least, not the answer I am hoping to find. I am attempting to convert a REGEXP_SUBSTR search from Teradata into T-SQL on SQL Server 2016.

This is the way it is written in Teradata:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(cn.CONTRACT_PD_AOR,'\b([a-zA-Z]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{3})(-([a-zA-Z]{2}))?\b')
```

The numbers in the curly brackets specify the number of characters that can match the specific REGEXP. So, this is looking for a contract number that look like this format: XX-99-999-XX

Is this not possible in T-SQL? Specifying the amount of characters to look at? So I would have to write something like this:

```
where CONTRACT_PD_AOR like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]%'
```

Is there not a simpler way to go about it?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex, so the short answer is "no". The long answer is that is you need true Regex support, you'll need to invest in CLR functions.

Comment: Man, that's crazy. Thanks for the info!

Comment: IMHO your best move is to migrate from SQL Server to Postgres. Not only will you save money, you'll enjoy a modern, fully-functional database.

Comment: Potential background: I believe the SQL Server LIKE operator was intentionally limited to expressions that can be evaluated in linear time with a single pass through the string being checked. No generated finite-state-machine. No backtracking. No lookahead.  No repetition qualifiers. No Nesting. Nothing that could make performance unpredictable. (And no reference to support my belief.)

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer, with this method it makes things a little less panful.  This is a way to set a format and reuse it if you'll need it multiple times in your code while keeping it clean and readable.

Set a format variable at the top, then do the needed replaces to build it. Then use the format name in the code.  Saves a little typing, makes your code less fugly, and has the benefit of making that format variable reusable should you need it in multiple queries without all that typing.

```
Declare @fmt_CONTRACT_PD_AOR nvarchar(max) = 'XX-99-999-XX';
Set @fmt_CONTRACT_PD_AOR = REPLACE(@fmt_CONTRACT_PD_AOR, '9', '[0-9]');
Set @fmt_CONTRACT_PD_AOR = REPLACE(@fmt_CONTRACT_PD_AOR, 'X', '[a-zA-Z]');

with tbl(str) as (
select 'AA-23-234-ZZ' union all
select 'db-32-123-dd' union all
select 'ab-123-88-kk'
)
select str from tbl
where str like @fmt_CONTRACT_PD_AOR;
```

Comment: Nice work around. But there are many other formats that it is searching for and new formats are added somewhat frequently. I guess I could just declare and set as many variables as we are searching for.